# Delta Hedging using another correlated asset

Tags: options, black-scholes

My question is about the following (from [Maxime de Bellefroid, Ch. 5 The Greeks](https://bookdown.org/maxime_debellefroid/MyBook/the-greeks.html)):
[image]

1. From my understanding $\Delta_2$ is the sensitive of the option (on the first instrument with underlying $S_1$) with respect to the price of the second instrument $S_2$, I guess this value can only be estimated and there are no closed formulas?
2. How is the value of $\frac{\partial S_2}{\partial S_1}$ calculated?

Answer (score 5):

Look carefully. $\frac{\partial S_2}{\partial S_1}$ is explicitly given as $\frac{\partial S_2}{\partial S_1} = \frac{\rho_{12}\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}\frac{S_2}{S_1}$

If you know the correlation and the standard deviations of daily returns for asset 1 and asset 2 you can use this formula. But if not you can just do a least squares regression of the daily price changes (not returns) of asset 2 on the daily price changes of asset 1 and essentially come up with the same result (remeber the formula for the slope on a bivariate regression, it is the correlation times the ratio of the two standard deviations).

Then the closed formula for finding $\Delta_2$ is $\Delta_2 = \Delta / \frac{\partial S_2}{\partial S_1}$, a simple division (let us hope the denominator is not zero).

Comment: When you say '$\frac{\partial{S_2}}{\partial{S_1}}$ is explicitly given' you mean that it is defined that way? If so why?

Comment: It is a poor explanation if you ask me, very confusing. He was able to write $\Delta_2 \frac{\partial S_2}{\partial S_1} =  
 \Delta_2 \rho_{12} \frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}\frac{S_2}{S_1}$ because he calculated for you what $\frac{\partial S_2}{\partial S_1}$ is equal to, but he does not show the details. So it is implicit, not explicit, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

This example is from Exotic Options and Hybrids: A Guide to Structuring, Pricing and Trading page 68 equation 5.3.

1. We are trying to find out $\Delta_2$, which is the amount of $S_2$ we need to perform delta hedge. We can use this chain rule equation to solve for $\Delta_2$. We only need to know $\Delta$ and $\frac{\partial S_2}{\partial S_1}$. The former is known and the latter depends on your assumption of asset price.
2. Here it assumes $S_1, S_2$ follow a bivariate geometric Brownian motion:

$$
\begin{align}
dS_1&=S_1\mu_1 dt+S_1\sigma_1dW_1
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
dS_2&=S_2\mu_2 dt+S_2\sigma_2dW_2
\end{align}
$$ with $$dW_1dW_2=\rho_{1,2} dt$$ This gives $\frac{\partial S_2}{\partial S_1} = \rho_{1,2} \frac{\sigma_2S_2}{\sigma_1S_1}$